# How to change dynamically the connexion login and password?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

In the configuration class I set the connexion caracteristics :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.ambre.pta")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/global.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/main.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:fr/admin.properties")
})
public class ApplicationContextConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() { // here is the connexion configuration
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
        dataSource.setUsername("pta");
        dataSource.setPassword("pta");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);

        sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.ambre.pta.model");

        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();

    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "utilisateurDao")
    public UtilisateurDAO getUtilisateurDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new UtilisateurDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "menuDao")
    public MenuDAO getMenuDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new MenuDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
    }

}
```

In our project , tracking user activities on the application is very important. So we need the user connected to be tracked in database when he  performed an action , such as clicking a menu ( calling a controller's action ) or submitting a form , and so on... That is why we need to set dynamically the connexion login , because if it is hardcoded to be "pta" then for every user using the app then it is written "pta" in the database log for every user using the app.

We already created a screen which creates users ; when a user is created then it is also created in the database ( Oracle ) : `create user xxx identified by pwd`. Then we created a screen which gives roles to the created user.

So when a user connects to the app then we need to make the database connexion with this user but not a hardcoded user which will remain the same for all users. How to do that ?

Comment: See [`UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.html). This also means you cannot use connection pooling anymore which can have a severe impact on your applications performance!

Comment: it uses the old xml based config ! I want to use java based config.

Comment: The way of configuration doesn't matter...

Comment: how can I modify my config class if using this class then ?

Comment: Just create an instance and set the properties. Create a `Filter` or `Interceptor` which, based on the logged in user, calls the `setCredentialsForCurrentThread` method and when the request has finished calls the `removeCredentialsFromCurrentThread`.

Comment: why just for the current thread ? I want it to be alive until the user disconnects.

Comment: requests are per handled on a thread. Each request has its own thread, so you need to set it for each request... You cannot set it once, you need to reset it each time.